# complex query in typeorm

Tags: database, typescript, typeorm

hello every body i have entity that contain special property used for translation, when i try to get this special property usin typeorm i have this error: (node:3712) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "[">>>

the entity is:

```
    import {
        Entity,
        PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
        Column, 
        BaseEntity, 
        OneToOne,
        JoinColumn,
        
        
      } from "typeorm";
      import {TextData} from "./TextData"
    
    @Entity()
    export class ContactUsDataNature extends BaseEntity {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number
    
    @OneToOne((type) => TextData, (text) => text.id, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    dataNature:TextData
    
    }
```

the text data is:

```
    import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, BaseEntity } from "typeorm";
    
    @Entity()
    export class TextData extends BaseEntity{
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;
    
        @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
        ar: string;
    
        @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
        en: string;
    
    }
```

i usually reach it like

```
    const contact=new ContactUSDataNature()
    console.log(contact.dataNature[en])
```

i tried the way to search but it doesn't work :

```
export const getContactDataNaturebyData = async (dataNature: string,language="en") =>{
  const container=await ContactUsDataNature.find({
    
    where: (qb) => {
        if (true) {
            qb.andWhere("ContactUsDataNature__dataNature.:lan = :parentId", {
              lan:"en",  
              parentId: 1,
            });
        }
       
    },
    order: { id: "DESC" },
    skip: 10,
    take: 0,
    });
    console.log(container)
    return container
    }
```

I need to get search in database for ContactUsDataNature if i get the final string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot parameterize the column names in a query.

You can build the where by concatenating the column name:

```
qb.andWhere("ContactUsDataNature__dataNature." + lan + " = :parentId", { parentId: 1 });
```

When you test this, I recommend that you turn on TypeOrm full logging so you can see the actual generated SQL and you be able to quickly solve any problems. See [TypeOrm logging](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md).

Comment: thanks....

it works but I tried to avoid "sql Injection"